# Define multiple function in loop using R

Tags: r

Below are code for the multiple testings on one variable (see):

```
## read data

library(foreign)

ml <- read.dta("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/hsbdemo.dta")

## define the reference group
ml$prog2 <- relevel(ml$prog, ref = "academic")

## starting to do the test, here is one result
test <- multinom(prog2 ~ ses, data = ml)

summary(test) ## need to display this

### caculate the z value

z <- summary(test)$coefficients/summary(test)$standard.errors
z   ## this output need to display

### caculate the p value

# 2-tailed z test
p <- (1 - pnorm(abs(z), 0, 1)) * 2
p   ## this output need to display.
```

Since in the date sets have multiple variable (for example: "female" "ses"  "schtyp"), i tried to write a loop to generate all the required output indicated above, using the below code :

```
## read the data

ml <- read.dta("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/hsbdemo.dta")

ml$prog2 <- relevel(ml$prog, ref = "academic")

## Here define the varlist

varlist <- names(ml)[2:4]
varlist

### define the for loop to do the analysis for the three varible defined above

models <- lapply(varlist, function(x) {
multinom(substitute(prog2 ~ i, list(i = as.name(x))), data = ml)
})

models
```

By doing this, it can only display the output for the first required output, how to improve this to also include the other two output? or we add another function within the function?

Answer (score 1):

You can return multiple items from your function with a list. But it looks like there is something odd about how `multinom` (which I assume is from the `nnet` package) tries to evaluate its parameter when you call `summary()` on a fitted model. I also changed your `lappy` to `Map` in order to  return a named list.

```
varlist
[1] "female" "ses"    "schtyp"

library(nnet)
models <- Map(function(x) {
  f <- substitute(prog2 ~ i, list(i = as.name(x)))
  mm <- eval(bquote(multinom(.(f), data = ml)))
  ms <- summary(mm) 
  z <- ms$coefficients/ms$standard.errors
  p <- (1 - pnorm(abs(z), 0, 1)) * 2
  list(ms , z, p)
}, varlist)

models
```

this returns a nested list such that

```
model$female[[1]] #summary
model$female[[2]] #z-values
model$female[[3]] #p-values
```

The same goes for the rest of the coefficients.